# JavaScript generate a string contains 1M random number browser crash

Tags: javascript

```
var text = "";
var possible = "0123456789";

for( var i=0; i < 10000000; i++ )
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
```

each time I run this code, the browser start to crash.How could I solve this?
because I need to use such long string to sort phone number(bitmap sorting).
the forloop may works but it took a long time.
so I think my problem is there any other way to make this faster than simple string concat.

Comment: Is there an actual reason you need to do this?

Comment: You code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ghcqhfad/1/),  it takes time, but still works.. (This is updated 10000000 ver.)

Comment: that's because i<5 .but when it comes to i<1000000 it starts crash

Comment: I ran the fiddle successfully as well.  What do you mean "starts crash"?

Comment: Try this alternative: https://jsfiddle.net/ghcqhfad/2/

Comment: This seems like an arbitrary task. Please specify what you are trying to achieve with this random number string.

Comment: To start off, your code is a bit inefficient, there are plenty of places you can cut down on computation. Other than that, if you want to generate a 1M long string, it's just going to be slow. Get a supercomputer or tone it down, I don't even know what the applications for this are.

Comment: It's working with IE and Chrome...  what browser are you working with?